# PFFacebookUtils Immediately calls block

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-login

I am making an iOS app that uses Facebook for login, and works with parse. I wanted to use ParseUI for login, and got everything setup, but the delegate methods never get called. I did a bit of digging, and think there is something wrong with PFFacebookUtils, or at least how I have set it up.

When I tested the PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions method, the block immediately gets called, with PFUser being null, as well as NSError being null. Facebook still appears to go through it's normal login flow, but never actually logs into my app.

I have been able to successfully log into Facebook(but not with parse) using just the Facebook sdk.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [Parse setApplicationId:@"censored"
              clientKey:@"censored"];
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Callback");
        NSLog(@"User: %@, error: %@", user, error);
    }];

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation];
}
```

I've also tried calling from a view controller:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    super viewDidLoad];
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Callback");
        NSLog(@"User: %@, error: %@", user, error);
    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

I've also tried dispatching it from a global thread, and on the main thread, with no luck.

This is how I got to login using Facebook SDK alone:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"User id: %@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID);
}

- (void) loginButton:   (FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:  (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
           error:   (NSError *)error{
    if( result.isCancelled ){
        NSLog(@"Cancelled login");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Login successful");
        NSLog(@"User id: %@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID);

    }
}

- (void) loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton{
    NSLog(@"Logout button");
}
@end
```

Comment: What about adding it in a `viewDidAppear` method to give sdk time to initialize? Normally, you would use `enableAutomaticUser` and only ask the user to log in to facebook when absolutely required, so maybe delaying the call to `PFFacebookUtils` would help. And make sure you've followed the facebook setup for ios apps.

Comment: Which versions of parse and of facebook sdk are you using?